# Do I lose translations when I change my Text domain for my plugin on wp.org?

Tags: plugin-development, localization, wordpress.org

In readme

```
 * Text Domain:       advanced-responsive-video-embedder
```

Do I lose translations when I change my language domain for my plugin on wp.org?

I am annoyed by `advanced-responsive-video-embedder` string and like to move to `arve` but I fear this will remove the already done translations.

Comment: For questions about  wordpress.org specifically you would be better asking wordpress.org than posting on another site, this isn't strictly about WordPress but rather it's about the website at wordpress.org and the plugin repo. The canonical place to ask this question is either in the meta slack channel on make WP slack, or on the .org support forums, both are 100x more likely to give you an answer, and not only that the correct answer straight from the people who maintain the code that determines the answer

Comment: "Asking wordpress.org" like it's a person I just can ask a question. You mean that support forums that that flooded by noobs who do not even know the most basic things? I actually think my chances are better here.

Comment: I could email `plugins@wordpress.org` though. I just thought somebody here just knows fast.

Comment: _there is a dedicated Slack channel on the Make WP slack with office hours staffed by the people who manage that part of the site intended for people with questions_

Answer (score 0):

I actually got a superfast response from the plugins mail. I'm assuming it's cool if I make this public.

> > I am wondering if I do I lose translations when I change my "Text Domain: xxxxx" inside my readme?
>
> Yes but ...
>
> You can't change that. Well, you can, but the WordPress translation
> system will always default to your plugin permalink. So it should
> always be whatever the plugin permalink is.
>
> Please re-read:
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#text-domains

---

> > By "defaults to" you mean its just always uses the slug no matter what is in there?
>
> The translation system here (glotpress) always uses the permalink, no
> matter what.
>
> > If it always uses the plugins permalink slug can I just remove it? Is there even a point in having it in the readme for wp.org plugins
> > then?
>
> Yep, you totally can remove it. People keep it in there when they want
> to handle their own translations.